# Intermec Printer Language - Tabulation Problem

Tags: intermec, ipl

I'm an ABAP programmer and I was asked to make a minor modification to an IPL label.
Easily done, but now I was tasked to fix a long running error within said label.
I know nothing about IPL and the lack of a online viewer makes everything worse...

The problem is that "tabulation" right in the middle of a text (I underlined it in blue on the Label's pic).
I checked the code and there's nothing there that should make that tabulation appear.
I spent a whole month reading manuals and trying to fix it, but nothing changes...

Here's the code and the resulting label:

```
<STX>R<ETX>
<STX><ESC>C<SI>W791<SI>h<ETX>
<STX><ESC>P<ETX>
<STX>F*<ETX>
<STX>H1;f3;o220,52;c34;b0;h2;w1;d3,300052947-FANDANGOS PRESUNTO 140GX14 LD<ETX>
<STX>H2;f3;o130,52;c33;b0;h1;w1;d3,Val:<ETX>
<STX>H3;f3;o130,204;c34;b0;h1;w1;d3,QTD.Unidade:<ETX>
<STX>H4;f3;o90,33;c34;b0;h0;w1;d3,16/08/21<ETX>
<STX>H5;f3;o90,302;c34;b0;h1;w1;d3,14<ETX>
<STX>B6;f3;o375,44;c2,0;w6;h102;r0;d3,17892840816329<ETX>
<STX>H7;f3;o275,44;c26;b0;h17;w17;d3,17892840816329<ETX>
<STX>H8;f3;o130,490;c34;b0;h0;w1;d3,Lote:<ETX>
<STX>B9;f3;o090,600;c2,0;w2;h45;r0;d3,0005218177<ETX>
<STX>H10;f3;o130,600;c34;b0;h0;w1;d3,0005218177<ETX>
<STX>D0<ETX>
<STX>R<ETX>
<STX><SI>l13<ETX>
<STX><ESC>E*,1<CAN><ETX>
<STX><RS>1000<US>1<ETB><ETX>
```

[Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30kiw.png)

Can you guys help me, please??

Edit: Just to make it clear, I did that blue line on that image to show what's the problem.

Here are some tests I did by changing the data:
[Test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFkkW.png)
[Test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2Hq.png)

The error always appear at the same point in the label, as long as there's a space in that text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the raw data of the output?  Is it POSSIBLE that what looks like a space is actually some special character that is making IPL choke blue?  Because it is literally the 1 character between the "O" and "1".  For grins, you might also try to change the character in the data to a "-" just for purposes of confirming data context.  It might even just be a TAB character.

I have done IPL years ago and have actually gone to the point of defining a pre-defined label template and generating output that says to use template X (whatever # I created as),and pass the data along that fills into the respective fields.

A final option I would throw in is this.  Take the sample output you have and just force sample data into each of the output areas.  So, instead of your literal data, put fake data in similar context just to see if it is data specific or other. Such as

```
<STX>H1;f3;o220,52;c34;b0;h2;w1;d3,300052947-FANDANGOS PRESUNTO 140GX14 LD<ETX>
```

becomes

```
<STX>H1;f3;o220,52;c34;b0;h2;w1;d3,123456789-TESTING-SAMPLEDATA-123XY12-AB<ETX>
```

Notice same context of data, but no spaces and using dash "-" just for testing.  Is there something special about the actual data.  This is a good way I have done historically for similar strangeness early on doing IPL labels.

Comment: Heya! That blue line was me, just to show what exactly was the problem. The problem isn't the text itself. I tried using different texts and that tabulation appears always at the same part of the label. If there are no "spaces", the tabulations doesn't appear.

Comment: @gmatheus.silva, That was my point, I have had data where white-space non-printable characters throw things off.  So an ASCII character 9 is the tab.  You can't SEE that its a tab, but  can cause issue.  Or some other character.  You could also break into two labels.  One with the leading numeric portion of the data, and a second label with proper offset second on the same output line.

Comment: Breaking it into 2 labels is a great idea! I'll modify the code and try to convince user to test it out for me. Thank you!

Comment: @gmatheus.silva, yeah, it looks like a string limit that is choking (doesnt make sense), but if the split label does NOT work, let me know and I'll see if I can dig-up some old documentation on IPL and refresh myself with it some as needed.

Comment: Heya! Unfortunately, user doesn't want to test this anymore... I guess I spent too much time on it before asking for help me... 
But thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

User decided to not spend anymore time on this issue, so now I'm unable to further test the label.
Unfortunately this problem will go unsolved for now. Hope I get another chance to fix this and learn more about IPL.
Thanks you so much for your answers!